# How to pass resource from a Gearman worker to client

Tags: php, resources, gearman

I have implemented connection pool in php with gearman. An old man techinque I know.

The concept is start a worker with x number of connections.
the client requests a connection and worker gives that.

However when I connect to db, I get a connection resource. How can I pass the connection resource to the client. If I pass resource it gives message that object cannot be converted to the string. If I serialize it the connection resource is lost.

my code

worker.php

```
//start worker
//addfunction ('getdb' 'getdb')

function getdb ($job){
$data = unserialize($job->workload();
$uname=$data['uname'];
$pasword=$data['pwd'];
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$password,$db);
return $con;
```

}

Client code

```
//gearman client
$connection = client->doNormal('getdb',serialize([$uname,$pass]));

var_dump($connection)
```

if I do var_dump on connection I see null or string 0, How can I get resource from worker to client over here.

Comment: You can not pass a `resource` from a worker to a client.

Comment: okay thats what I also feel. Is there an alternative?

Comment: May ask yourself why you want do this in that way. Why not just connect to the database in the client directly, because you want to use the database in the client not in the worker as i can see. Whatever, normaly you will connect in the Client or Worker directly to the Database if its needed. Client and Worker can only transfer strings to each other.

Comment: If you just want to reduce the reconnection to the database, may this will help you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: And I personally prefer PDO over mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Example #4

Comment: And as last not: Normaly Worker do Jobs. You call the Client and they deligate the call to a free worker to do the job/work.  And when you need more power, you start more worker to do the same job (may with different parameters) at the same time. The Client ist just the entry point.  So you call Client with paraemter x=y and any of the running worker will do the job and send the result back to your client.

Comment: Thank you for nice suggestions. My goal is to implement connection pooling in the php as Php does not have it, my idea is to have a worker run with connections open. whenever there is a requirement client requests the worker for connection.